# Where to ask: technicalities about TrueType fonts

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Some time ago I asked [a question](https://superuser.com/q/1318705/900518) on [super**user**](https://superuser.com/) site: "“The number of bars and waves”", dealing with a quite technical detail of TrueType. The question was well received but, no answers.

Is there a better SE site to ask this type of questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have another site in the network, [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), which deals with [fonts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts) from a graphical perspective. They should be able to tell you what the terminology means; how to change them is probably more at home on Super User (if it's a technical setting somewhere).

Comment: FYI: I came up with this as well but also checked UX.se where I consider it to be off-topic.